# Monkey patching values of a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, monkeypatching

I have a small function as follows:

```
def write_snapshot_backup_monitoring_values():
    try:
        snapshot_backup_result = 'my result'
        with open(config.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE, "w") as snapshot_backup_file:
            snapshot_backup_file.write(snapshot_backup_result)       
    except Exception as exception:
        LOG.exception(exception)
```

where `config.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE` is declared in a config file with value = `/home/result.log`

when I try to write a test case using pytest and I call this function as follows:

```
constants.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE = "/tmp/result.log"

@pytest.mark.functional_test
def test_write_snapshot_backup_monitoring_values():
    utils.write_snapshot_backup_monitoring_values()...
```

I want to monkey patch the value for `config.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE` with `constants.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE` which I have declared in the test case file. Basically I want that while runnning the test case it should create `/tmp/result.log` and not `/home/result.log` How can I do that? I am new to monkey patching in python.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but what if you passed in the name of the file as a parameter instead of having it hard coded into the function? Then in the test you could pass that other file in

Answer (score 1):

You don't clear up what `config` is, so I assume it is another module you have imported. There's no specific technique for monkey-patching, you just assign the value. It's just a name for adding/modifying attributes at runtime.

```
config.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE = constants.MONITOR_SNAPSHOT_BACKUP_FILE
```

However, there's one thing to keep in mind here: Python caches imported modules. If you change this value, it will change for other python modules that have imported `config` and run in the same runtime. So, be careful that you don't cause any side effects.